# how to escape string chars in PHP

Tags: php, html

I made an uploader for practice, in my form I have input type text which is the part of the directory it's going to upload,
I just use \ in input, it will mess up my directory code in PHP process it and upload somewhere else,
I try this

```
    if (empty($folder_name) || $folder_name== "\" ){
    echo "<h3>لطفا نام فولدر را انتخاب کنید</h3>";
}
else{
    uploader("$folder_name");
}
?>
```

but it didn't work, pls help me how I can exclude `"\"` string in PHP

Comment: guys thanks but I just found the problem, just a few minutes after submitting this

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What do you mean by "exclude"?

Answer (score 0):

for excluding `"\"` in PHP you can't use a single one `"\"`

```
if (empty($folder_name) || $folder_name== "\" )
```

instead of using one "" you should use "\"

```
if (empty($folder_name) || $folder_name== "\\" )
```

it did work correctly I hope this post helps someone else like me

Comment: you are doing what is called "escaping". the backslash \ will escape (treat just as string and not as php command) the char that immediately follow. If you have a `'` in a string for example you can do `\'` to avoid php parsing it

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to exclude the backslash from a string, you can use php's *stripslashes($string)*.
See documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

`$folder_name` without `"\"` would be:

```
$folder_name = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\FolderABC";
$folder_name = stripslashes($folder_name);
```

In this case it would return the string "C:UsersNameDesktopFolderABC"